# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "software.amazon.awssdk.http.async.SdkAsyncHttpClient.execute

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

> Getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "software.amazon.awssdk.http.async.SdkAsyncHttpClient.execute(software.amazon.awssdk.http.async.AsyncExecuteRequest)" because "this.sdkAsyncHttpClient" is null

COuld anyone please help, I am getting null value for "sdkAsyncHttpClient" (See blow code which is implemented in method ConnectMethod).

> CompletableFuture responseF = sdkAsyncHttpClient
> .execute(AsyncExecuteRequest.builder().request(sdkHttpFullReques)
> .requestContentPublisher(new SimpleHttpContentPublisher(sdkHttpFullReques))
> .responseHandler(responseHandler).build());

> Below is my test case for "ConnectMethod"

```
@InjectMocks
        private RequestServiceImpl service;
        @Mock
        private CommonUtils utils;
        @Mock
        private LogMetricsUtils logMetricsUtils;
        @Mock
        private ErrorMessageConstruction msg;
        @Mock
        SdkAsyncHttpClient sdkAsyncHttpClient;
        @Mock
        CompletableFuture<Void> res;
        @Test
            void ConnectMethod_Test() throws Exception {
                RequestServiceImpl s = new RequestServiceImpl();
                ReflectionTestUtils.setField(s, "resourcePathDispatcher",
                        "/it/psoit/combinedorch/v1/obligation-3.0/serviceobligation");
                ReflectionTestUtils.setField(s, // inject into this object
                        "baseURL", 
                        "http://os-api-connectMethod.os-dev.svc.cluster.local:8080");  injected
                Method method = RequestValidationServiceImpl.class.getDeclaredMethod("ConnectMethod",
                        ObligationRequest.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Value1.class, String.class,
                        String.class, String.class);
                method.setAccessible(true);
        
                method.invoke(s, RequestUtils.getObligationRequest(), Constants_Test.applicationId,
                        Constants_Test.applicationKey, uuid, RequestUtils.getValue1().get(0), Constants_Test.appContext,
                        Constants_Test.Operation, Constants_Test.auth);
```

> Below is the Java class methods for which i have written Junit test code

```
@Service
@Validated
public class RequestServiceImpl implements RequestService {

    Logger logHelper = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @Autowired
    private ErrorMessageConstruction msg;
    @Autowired
    private Clear utils;

    @Autowired
    SdkAsyncHttpClient sdkAsyncHttpClient;

    @Value("${url.base}")
    private String baseURL;

    @Value("${resource.path.dispatcher}")
    private String resourcePathDispatcher;

    @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store-password}")
    private String sslPassword;

    @Autowired
    PublisherService publisherService;

    @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store-password}")
    private String sslPwd;
    private static final String OS_OPERATION = "serviceobligation";
private List<Payload> ConnectMethod(ObligationRequest obligationRequest, final String appId, final String appKey,
            final String unitOfWorkId, Value1 request, String appContextName, String osOperation, String authHeader) {
        List<Payload> payloadList = new ArrayList<>();
        Instant startTime = Instant.now();
        RequestAcceptorRequest requestDispatcherRequest = getRequestDispatcherRequest(obligationRequest.getValue0(),
                request);
        try {
            SdkHttpFullRequest sdkHttpFullReques = getsdkHttpFullRequest(requestDispatcherRequest, appId, appKey,
                    unitOfWorkId, osOperation, authHeader);
            CombinedOrchCallMetrics metrics = getMetrics(appId, unitOfWorkId, requestDispatcherRequest, appContextName);
            List<Payload> response = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
            ResponseHandler responseHandler = new ResponseHandler(metrics, response);
            CompletableFuture<Void> responseF = sdkAsyncHttpClient
                    .execute(AsyncExecuteRequest.builder().request(sdkHttpFullReques)
                            .requestContentPublisher(new SimpleHttpContentPublisher(sdkHttpFullReques))
                            .responseHandler(responseHandler).build());
            try {
                responseF.join();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logHelper.error(Constants.ERROR_MSG, e.getMessage());
                throw new CommonException("Exception occured while merging response");
            }
            List<Payload> payloads = responseHandler.getResponseList();
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(payloads)) {
                payloadList.add(payloads.get(0));
            } else

                payloadList = msg.get521ErrorMessage(requestDispatcherRequest.getValue0().getUserLocale(),
                        requestDispatcherRequest.getValue1());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logHelper.error(Constants.ERROR_MSG, e.getMessage());
            Instant endTime = Instant.now();
            long timeTaken = Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toMillis();
            String msge = "Exception occurred while calling Combined Orch: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
            publisherService.logError(unitOfWorkId, unitOfWorkId, -1, appId, Constants.SERVICE_VERSION,
                    Constants.COMORC_SERVICE, msge, "", "", timeTaken, appContextName);
            payloadList = msg.get521ErrorMessage(requestDispatcherRequest.getValue0().getUserLocale(),
                    requestDispatcherRequest.getValue1());
            throw new CommonException("Exception occured while processing sdkHttpFullRequest");
        }
        return payloadList;
    }

    private SdkHttpFullRequest getsdkHttpFullRequest(RequestAcceptorRequest requestDispatcherRequest, String appId,
            String appKey, String unitOfWorkId, String osOperation, String authHeader) {

        logHelper.info("requestdispatcherURL: {} {}", baseURL, resourcePathDispatcher);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("applicationKey", appKey);
        headers.add("applicationId", appId);
        headers.add("unitOfWorkId", unitOfWorkId);
        headers.add("Authorization", authHeader);
        if (osOperation != null) {
            headers.add(Constants.HEADER_OS_OPERATION, osOperation);
        } else {
            headers.add(Constants.HEADER_OS_OPERATION, OS_OPERATION);
        }
        // For single serial number request transactionId=unitOfWorkId
        headers.add("transactionId", unitOfWorkId);
        headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        headers.add("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        URI uri = URI.create(baseURL);
        return SdkHttpFullRequest.builder().uri(uri).method(SdkHttpMethod.POST).encodedPath(resourcePathDispatcher)
                .applyMutation(b -> {
                    b.headers(headers);
                })
                .contentStreamProvider(() -> new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        CoreUtil.toString(RequestAcceptorRequest.class, requestDispatcherRequest)
                                .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                .build();
    }
```